# Foreach loop with Concatenation assignment

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, null

```
<?php
$names =array('Alex','Billy','Tabby');
$names_str=null;
foreach($names as $key => $names)
{
    $names_str .= $name;
    if(key!= (count($names)-1))
    {
        $names_str.=', ';
    }
}
echo $names_str;
?>
```

why do we set names_str=null?
why do we put count($names-1)) how does this loop work?

Comment: $names_str=null;  is declaring the var $names if not the .= operator inside the foreach raise an error for assigning a not existing var  .. the check for count is for append a comma at all  the values in array but not at the last  ..

Comment: setting `$names_str=null` is kind of initializing the `$name_str` variable with an empty value that it could be assigned to new value being concatenating from the loop  `count($names-1))` here is kind of a check which is check if the `$key` is as index is under array's total length and loop works in way that it picks up array's each item one by one and concatinate into a string which is to be assigned to `$names_str` hope this will help you understand.

Comment: And all this instead of `$names_str = implode(', ', $names);`

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$names = array('Alex','Billy','Tabby');
$names_str = null;
foreach($names as $key => $names)
{
    $names_str .= $name;
    if(key != (count($names) - 1))
    {
        $names_str .=', ';
    }
}
echo $names_str;
?>
```

**Why do we set `$names_str = null`?**

It is being initialized outside of the loop. If this is a string to be returned, technically doing `$names_str = "";` would work better if you want a default value to show and aren't doing some sort of empty/null check...

**Why do we put `count($names-1))`?**

This checks the key # e.g. (0,1,2) against the count/length of the array minus 1 (array starts at 0), to see if we are referencing the last key/value pair in the array, to determine if the string should show a comma between the current value and next value, or not. If it's the last value, we don't want to show a "," at the end of the string.

**How does this loop work?**

`$names_str .= $name;` concatenates the `$name` values to the initial string, with the if/key check placing commas between each value. See above about the count. So you end up with `"Alex, Billy, Tabby"` as the final value for `$names_str`.

A better way to do this is to use PHP's [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function:

```
$comma_separated = implode(",", $names);
```

This would give you the same comma separated list.